# Custom formatting for ipywidgets IntSlider

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I'm working on an interactive graph. One of the options is to select the number of rooms for a house. Right now, if you input any number above 5 in the `n_rooms` argument, the graph will always show data for houses that have 5 or more rooms. So I constructed this

```
n_rooms = widgets.IntSlider(
    min=1,
    max=5,
    description='number of rooms:',
    layout=Layout(width='30%'),
    style=style,
    disabled=False)
```

The thing is, this will show a slider that goes from 1 to 5. The only thing I want to change is that instead of showing '5', it shows '5 or more'. Is there any way to do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [selection slider](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Widget%20List.html#SelectionSlider) to use both integers and strings in sliders.

```
num_rooms = widgets.SelectionSlider(
options=['1', '2', '3', '4', '5 or more'],
value='1',
description='number of rooms:',
disabled=False,
continuous_update=False,
orientation='horizontal',
readout=True   )
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case (mostly displaying scientific data) it is helpful to define a `Text` widget and use it together with the Slider. You just have to set `readout=False` and use a `HBox`. For example, I have some field strengths stored in `intensities`:

```py
fs = IntSlider(
        description='fs: ',
        value=0, min=0, max=len(ints)-1,
        readout=False
    )
fs_text = Text(value=f'{ints[0]:.1f}V/nm', description='', layout=Layout(width='80px'))

# ...
# do some updates
# ...

HBox([fs, fs_text])
```

In this case you are free to do whatever you want with the text of `Text` in your update function.