# Displays the current value at the bottom of the SelectionRangeSlider Jupyter Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, widget, ipywidgets

I'm creating an interactive notebook by using the library ipywidgets. I'm interested in SelectionRangeSlider widget. In documentation, we have a simple example :

```
import datetime
dates = [datetime.date(2015, i, 1) for i in range(1, 13)]   
options = [(i.strftime('%b'), i) for i in dates]
widgets.SelectionRangeSlider(
options=options,
index=(0, 11),
description='Months (2015)',
disabled=False
)
```

That creates folowing slider :

[image]

I would like to change the position of the current values selected, putting it at the bottom, like that:

[image]

I've read documentation but I couldn't find a way to do this. Anyone knows if it's even possible to change this position? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Others have done things like this by setting `readout=False` and then making a separate widget to display the updated values. See these examples:

- [workaround  offered by marcusreaiche for SelectionRangeSlider](https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/issues/2855#issuecomment-966747483)
- [TheIdealis' answer to 'Custom formatting for ipywidgets IntSlider'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65814595/8508004)