# Partially visible text for ipywidgets

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, ipywidgets, bqplot

I have made a `selection_range_slider` in jupyter notebook using `ipywidgets`, the only issue is that we can't see the end of the second date. What modification should I make to make this visible? (see picture below)

[image]

Here is my code:

```
    start_date = datetime(2019, 4, 24)
    end_date = date.today()

    dates = pd.date_range(start_date, end_date, freq='D')

    options = [(date.strftime(' %d %b %Y '), date) for date in dates]
    index = (0, len(options)-1)

    selection_range_slider = widgets.SelectionRangeSlider(
        options=options,
        index=index,
        description='Dates',
        continuous_update=False,
        orientation='horizontal',
        layout={'width': '800px'},
        placeholder='Type something'
     )

    selection_range_slider.observe(change_scatter_chart, names="value")
    selection_range_slider

    widgets.VBox([selection_range_slider, fig])
```

Comment: it may need to use `CSS` to change it.

Comment: Can you add the code to your question?

Comment: @Godjenka, itepifano wisely requested you add the code to the question. Use a code block to add it to your post by editing it.  The comment you added has no indenting apparent and has all the lines as run on.

Comment: For an alternative solution where you make a separate HTML text item showing the current, selection see the first option listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72218747/8508004). You may want to read that entire thread at [the final link](https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/issues/2855#issuecomment-966747483) as it is pertinent to your question and maybe an alternative there covers what you need in a simpler way.

Answer (score 0):

**1st option**: Modify `layout={'width' : '800px'}` into `layout={'width' : '700px'}`

or

**2nd option:** put this at the beginning of your script

```
from IPython.display import display, HTML
display(HTML(data="""<style>div#notebook-container{ width: 100%; }</style>"""))
```